# Modulus of a torus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

Suppose I have a torus (you can pretend that it is the usual torus of revolution: the boundary of a tubular neighborhood of radius $r_2$ of a circle of radius $r_1.$ The question is: can one compute its modulus in terms of $r_1$ and $r_2?$ Of course, one can have knotted embeddings, where the question is also interesting, but we can start here.

Comment: Could you add a definition of "modulus"?

Comment: @Igor Belegradek: there is a conformal map $f$ of a rectangle $[0,1]\times[0,a]$ onto the torus, such that $f(a,y)=f(0,y), 0<y<1,$ and $f(x,1)=f(x,0), 0<x<a$. He is asking how to express $a$ in terms of $r_1,r_2$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I thought, modulus is defined for a family of curves. There are many ways a torus can be written as the union of such a family.  Can different families lead to different answers?

Comment: Modulus can be defined in terms of a family of curves. The definition I gave is equivalent. In general, a modulus of a torus is a number that distinguishes conformally non-equivalent tori. Conformal classes of tori form a complex 1-parametric family. But in this problem the modulus is a real number in view of symmetry.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237388/conformal-equivalence-of-tori.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thanks! That works.

Answer (score 6):

Let $a=r_1/r_2>1$. Then the modulus is
$$\sqrt{a^2-1}.$$
Here is my calculation: parameterize the torus in the natural way:
$$x=(r_1+r_2\cos\theta_2)\cos\theta_1,$$
$$y=(r_1+r_2\cos\theta_2)\sin\theta_1,$$
$$z=r_2\sin\theta_2.$$
Then the restriction of the Euclidean metric from $R^3$ to the torus
in coordinates $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ is
$$dx^2+dy^2+dz^2=(r_1+r_2\cos\theta_2)^2d\theta_1^2+r_2^2d\theta_2^2,$$
which is proportional to
$$(a+\cos\theta_2)^2d\theta_1^2+d\theta_2^2.$$
Now, let find a conformal map of the square
$\{(\theta_1,\theta_2)\in [0,2\pi]^2\}$ with this metric onto a rectangle
with coordinates $x,y$ with Euclidean metric. Let
$\theta_1=x,\theta_2=v(y)$, where
$v$ solves
$$
\frac{dv}{dy}=a+\cos v.\tag{1}$$
The pull back of the metric
into $(x,y)$ plane is then
$$(a+\cos v)^2dx^2+(a+\cos v)^2dy^2$$
so the metric is conformally equivalent to the Euclidean one. It remains to find the shape of the rectangle in
the $(x,y)$-plane. One side is $2\pi$, and another side is
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dv}{a+\cos v}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}},$$
and their ratio (the modulus)
is $\sqrt{a^2-1}$. (Or $1/\sqrt{a^2-1})$ depending on your exact definition of the modulus.)

Comment: I am confused by this, because when $r_2$ approaches $r_1$ your modulus approaches $0,$ but this can't be right.

Comment: It depends what you call modulus: the extremal length of the curve family in the class of the equator, or the extremal length of the curves in the class of the meridian. They are reciprocal to each other. Of course when $r_2$ approaches $r_1$, the torus degenerates, and its modulus tends to $0$ or $\infty$ depending on your choice of definition.

Comment: Sometimes the $j$-invariant is used as the modulus: in this case it is $j(\sqrt{1-a^2})$.

Comment: I did not notice that this solution has already been posted on MathSE (see the comment of @IgorBelegradek to this question. So you can remove the question and answer.

Comment: We must have a different understanding of the radii. When $r_1$ approaches $r_2$ the torus becomes very fat (a tubulular neighborhood of radius close to $1$ around a curve of radius $1.) This is the opposite of "degenerate" in my book. When there is exact equality, the torus is not embedded, but just before then...

Comment: My understanding was that you have a circle $C=\{(x,y,0):x^2+y^2=r_1^2\}$, and the torus is described by the circles of radius $r_2$ whose centers are on $C$, and the planes are perpendicular to $C$. So when $r_2\to 0$, the torus degenerates to the first circle, and when $r_2\to r_1$ the torus degenerates in another way: becomes too fat and develops a singularity at the origin.

Comment: In my terminology, the torus "degenerates" either way: when $r_1\to 0$ and when $r_2\to r_1$, since for these limit values it is not a torus anymore:-)

Comment: Yes. So, when $r_1 =1$ and $r_2 = 0.999,$ the surface is fat and embedded, and I cannot see why the modulus should be near $0.$

Comment: Of course, when there is exact equality, not only is the torus not embedded, but it also is not a torus.

Comment: @Igor Rivin: Think of the modulus in terms of extremal length: when $r_2$ is close to $r_2$ the surface contains an loop small loop of radius $r_1-r_2$ in one homology class.

Comment: @Igor Rivin: What happens to a ring in the plane of radii $0<R_1<R_2$. The ring degenerates when $R_1$ tend s to $0$ or to $R_2$. The situation is very similar.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Yes, I figured this out. Weird.